# JavaScript checking to see if a sum is correct

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im wanting javascript to check to see if the user has given the correct answer to two random numbers generated by php. The user manually enters the number in the text box provided.

```
<input id="number1" name="number1" readonly="readonly" class="Add" value="<?php echo rand(1,4) ?>" /> + 
<input id="number2" name="number2" readonly="readonly" class="Add" value="<?php echo rand(5,9) ?>" /> =
<input type="text" name="answer" id="number" class="number" maxlength="2" />
<span id="comment"><div class="Lable">Please give the correct answer to the sum</div></span>
```

JavaScript

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function validate()
{

if (Contact.answer.value == Contact.number1.value + Contact.number2.value)
{
    alert("Wrong answer number")
    return false
}

return true;

}



</script>
```

Iv give it a shot but my JavaScript skills are almost none existent

Comment: Be aware of using such technique for preventing spammers or bots. You cannot ever trust a clientside validation.

Comment: use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` on your numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you call `validate()` on the form's `submit` event (i.e. `onsubmit="validate()"`). If not, you'll need to call the function somehow.

Secondly, your logic is the wrong way around. You're checking if the answer is correct (that's what `==` does), and then telling the user it's incorrect when it's correct, and allowing it when it's not.

Change your logic around as follows:

```
function validate()
{
    if((parseInt(Contact.number1.value) + parseInt(Contact.number2.value)) == Contact.answer.value)
    {
        return true;
    }   

    alert("Wrong answer number")
    return false
}
```

Notice that we also use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to prevent JavaScript treating the values as strings, and then concatenating them with the `+` literal. If we don't use `parseInt()`, JavaScript will interpret `6` and `4` as `64`, rather than `10`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Iv pasted your code in and it seems to be stopping my validation all together. And yes I do have the return validate() on submit.

Comment: Sorry, there was a syntax error (missing `)`) in the code I posted. Please try the code in the updated answer.

Comment: Perfect Thanks for you help with this! And to everyone who commented and helped!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function validate()
{
var answer = parseInt(document.getElementById("number1").value,     10)+parseInt(document.getElementById("number2").value, 10);
var v = parseInt(document.getElementById("captcha").value, 10);
if (answer != v)
{
    alert("Wrong answer number")
    return false
}

return true;
}



</script>
```